# JasperReports - Handle big data from database to PDF

Tags: java, performance, io, jasper-reports

I have a report that takes a select that return me about 900k records (it´s about 100MB of data) and I need to create a *PDF* with it.

So, my implementation is simple: I get the data from my JDBC Query, put into a `ArrayList` and pass it to my report. I had some problems with memory but I fixed it, my problem now is with CPU processing (it is always at 100%) that makes my process crash.

My code is really simple:

```
 public OutputStream getOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperName, params, fillList);
            JRExporter exporter = format.getExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
            exporter.exportReport();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error getting the stream", e);
        }
        return out;
    }
```

I would like to know:

- How in this case could I use my CPU´s multiple cores?
- Is there another strategy to do that?

Comment: When you say your CPU is always at 100%, do you mean all the cores are at 100%? Just one? And what to you mean by crashes? Do you get some type of stack trace or something. It might be useful to include if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things which I would suggest.
1. Try firing the **query from the JasperReport** itself rather than storing it in Arraylist and then passing it to report.

2.Use **Report Virtualizer**.Depending upon your need you can either use Swap Virtualizer or Gzip virtualizer. Jasper claims that Gzip virtualizer compresses the jasper object to 1/10th of the original jasper object.

Virtualizer will ensure no matter how big your data is report is always generated using the virtualizer. I have personally printed over 25000 reports exceeding 500MB size report using GZip virtualizer to ensure that it is indeed working properly.